# How to change the Xfce4 default window manager?

Tags: window-manager, xfce, xfwm4

How can I change the default window manager for Xfce4?

For some reason, `xfwm` doesn't run when I run xfce4 shell.

Comment: How are you starting the xfce4 shell?

Comment: You use the `--replace` order in a command, such as `compiz --replace` to use Metacity in XFCE or Emerald if it's Installed..

Comment: Already tried it with xfwm4 --replace but it doesn't last after logging off.

Comment: **How are you starting the xfce4 shell?**

Comment: just choosing xfce session in lightdm

Answer (score 17):

Doing `YourWindowManager --replace` means xfwm4 has already started upon login and you are now stopping it to start a new window manager...that's working but there's a quicker and cleaner way as [this guy explains](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0xTiTUiIng) taking kwin as his example.

XFCE starts the window manager specified in `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml` or, under xubuntu, in `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml`

In this file look for the `Client0_Command` property and edit its value: `<value type="string" value="xfwm4"/>` to `<value type="string" value="kwin"/>` (obviously, replace "kwin" with your window manager of choice) You would need to go root. You could also copy and only edit that file in `/home/user/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml` if you want the changes to only affect your userspace.

Because in XFCE it is common for us to save our session while logging out, don't forget to clean your session: Settings Manager->Session and Startup->Session tab->Clear saved sessions

Now you can logout and back in.

Comment: You could do the same from the command line using `xfconf-query --channel xfce4-session --property /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command --set openbox --force-array` (change `openbox` to your preferred window manager).

Comment: @Mikel This gives me "There are 1 new values, but only 2 types could be determined."

Comment: @d33tah This command worked for me with xfconf version 4.12.1: `xfconf-query --channel xfce4-session --property /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command --type string --set "awesome" --force-array`

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way I found to permanently change the default window manager is:

1. Download your desired WM.
2. Then go: system tools > preferences > startup applications.
3. Then click "add".
4. If you wanted, for example, to change your default WM to metacity, at "name" put "metacity" and at "command" put "metacity --replace". Click "add".
5. Log out > log in.

Answer (score 3):

In general...

1. Download your desired window manager if you don't already have it
2. Run it with --replace, so for the XFCE default manager `xfwm4 --replace`
3. Log out, but ensure that you have checked the 'Save session for future logins' option. The logout dialog, if otherwise unavailable, can be invoked from a command line `xfce4-session-logout`

Answer (score 1):

To change it to xfwm4, the following command should work. This would change it back to the setting Xfce has by default out of the box.

`xfconf-query --channel xfce4-session --property /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command --type string --set 'xfwm4' --type string --set '--replace'`

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer a GUI solution, go to:

Settings >> Desktop Settings. In the Desktop Settings dialog, change the Window Manager to the manager of your choice.

[Desktop Settings, Window Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdETp.png)

This works in Linux Mint 20.2

Comment: Greetings, as LM is not an official Ubuntu derivative, I am voting to delete this as a non-answer. If you wish to post an update relevant to Ubuntu, I'd be happy to reverse the vote. As a LM user, you are more then welcome to post LM related solution on a dedicated LM forum.